# parsing a special format file in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm trying to parse a special format file in c++, but i'm out of ideas on how to do so:

first of all this is the file format:

```
("special format file"
    : (dir1
        : (dir2
            : (dir3
                :key1 (1)
                :key2 (1)
                :key3(1)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I want the user to give me a path (dir1//dir2/dir3 for example) and I want to return to him all the keys of the given path (key1,2,3) in the example above.

How can I iterate in the code to the given path and print out all the keys?

Comment: Did you try to check line by line (there is key + special name)? And did you try to check via TAB symbol?

Comment: check [boost spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/introduction.html).